# Converting a date time field in crystal report to date field

Tags: date

I am trying to link two different tables by date.  table 1: Date is a date and time field table 2: Date is a date field

I am using Crystal report 11 and in the report options; converting to the date field is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Can't do such a join in Crystal.
Consider creating a View in the DBMS to take care of converting the data type in one of these tables.

Other options:

1. No join but use a record selection condition. Performance would suffer but if number of records is not too large that should work.
2. Use a Command.
3. Use one table in the main report and link to the other via a subreport link.